# Error Resource ID #0x0 using setImageResource Android Adapter RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, material-design

I'm learning Android, and I have a problem with my Adapter. I can get the Text in the Adapter but, I have problems with Setting the Image Source.

[[This is the result if i comment the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mR0sl.jpg) ]

[[this is an example of what i want but setting the images from my array.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m02JP.jpg)

I use integer-array with item drawable in `arrays.xml`

```
<integer-array name="champ_image">
        <item>@drawable/aatrox</item>
        <item>@drawable/ahri</item>
        <item>@drawable/akali</item>
        <item>@drawable/alistar</item>
        <item>@drawable/amumu</item>
        <item>@drawable/anivia</item>
        <item>@drawable/ashe</item>
    </integer-array>
```

Here is my Error LogCat:

```
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.sagar.materialdesigndemo, PID: 19392
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1307)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:826)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:403)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:177)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:170)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:53)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:74)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sagar.adapters.ChampAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ChampAdapter.java:55)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sagar.adapters.ChampAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ChampAdapter.java:15)
01-04 03:09:30.057 19392-19392/com.sagar.materialdesigndemo E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5212)
```

Here is my Adapter called `ChampAdapter`, I think the problem is in: `holder.champImg.setImageResource(champItem.get(position).champImg); //HERE`

```
public class ChampAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChampAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<ChampionItemModel> champItem;

    public ChampAdapter(List<ChampionItemModel> champItem){this.champItem = champItem;}

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView champName;
        TextView roleChamp;
        ImageView champImg;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.champName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.champ_name);
            this.roleChamp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.champ_role);
            this.champImg = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.champ_image);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_champs,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.itemView.setClickable(true);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){

            }
        });

        holder.champName.setText(champItem.get(position).champName);
        holder.roleChamp.setText(champItem.get(position).roleChamp);
        holder.champImg.setImageResource(champItem.get(position).champImg); //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { return champItem.size();}

}
```

And here is the rest of the code

- Model:

  ```
  public class ChampionItemModel {

      public String champName;
      public String roleChamp;
      public int champImg;

      public ChampionItemModel(String champName, String roleChamp, int champImg){
          this.champName = champName;
          this.roleChamp = roleChamp;
          this.champImg = champImg;
      }
  }
  ```
- Fragment method called `initializeChampsItemList`:

  ```
  private void initializeChampsItemList(){
          ChampionItemModel championItemModel;
          String[] champsNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.champ_name);
          String[] champsRoles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.champ_role);
          int[] champsImages = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.champ_image);
          final int length = champsNames.length;
          for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
              championItemModel = new ChampionItemModel(champsNames[i], champsRoles[i], champsImages[i]);
              champItems.add(championItemModel);
          }

      }
  ```

Comment: Show `champ_image ` Array xml

Comment: i have updated the post with the arrays.xml

Comment: See my answer which help you in solving issue.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in `arrays.xml` `champ_image` Array item is `@drawable/aatrox` means `champ_image` is typed Array instead of `int`. so use `obtainTypedArray` method which return `TypedArray` as:

```
TypedArray imgsTypedArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.champ_image);
```

Now use `TypedArray.getResourceId` to get drawable id's and pass it to `ChampionItemModel` as:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
  int drawableId= imgsTypedArray.getResourceId(i, -1);
  championItemModel = new ChampionItemModel(champsNames[i], 
                                 champsRoles[i], 
                                 drawableId);
  champItems.add(championItemModel);
}
```

Comment: OMG you are the best, Thanks you a lot. =D!!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to load images from drawable folder.
Then declare 'champsImages' array like following:

int[] champsImages = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, ...to more};

I think it will help to achieve your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray

XML file saved at res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <array name="icons">
     <item>@drawable/home</item>
     <item>@drawable/settings</item>
     <item>@drawable/logout</item>
   </array>
   <array name="colors">
     <item>#FFFF0000</item>
     <item>#FF00FF00</item>
     <item>#FF0000FF</item>
   </array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves each array and then obtains the first entry in each array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray icons = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.icons);
Drawable drawable = icons.getDrawable(0);

TypedArray colors = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.colors);
int color = colors.getColor(0,0);
```